# Shared objects in shared objects with multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, shared-memory, python-multiprocessing

I face a very persistent problem: I'd like to share complex objects between processes using the process-shareable types proposed in `multiprocessing`(such as `dict`, `list`, etc. which have proxies handled by `SyncManager`). I even implemented a few other common types such as `deque` and `set`. Everything works as long as I store simple values in those objects (floats, integers, etc.).

For instance, if I use the following, this works perfectly as expected:

```
import multiprocessing, time

manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
d       = manager.list()
lock    = manager.Lock()

def reader(d, lock):
    for i in range(5):
        with lock:
            print(d)
            sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.5)

def writer(d, lock):
    for i in range(5):
        with lock:
            d.append(i)
        time.sleep(0.5)

# Try to read and write the deque:
r = multiprocessing.Process(target=reader, args=(d, lock))
w = multiprocessing.Process(target=writer, args=(d, lock))
r.start()
w.start()
r.join()
w.join()
```

As expected, this output the updated list at each iteration of the reader.

A problem arises when I want to store objects in those objects. Let's say a dictionary of lists. Obviously, if I store simple objects in a process-shareable dict, that won't do it. So I tried the following:

```
import multiprocessing, time

manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
d       = manager.dict()
lock    = manager.Lock()

# Add lists:
for i in range(5):
    d[i] = manager.list()

def reader(d, lock):
    for i in range(10):
        with lock:
            print(d)
            sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(1)

def writer(d, lock):
    for i in range(10):
        with lock:
            for j in range(5):
                d[j].append(i)
        time.sleep(1)

# Try to read and write the dict:
r = multiprocessing.Process(target=reader, args=(d, lock))
w = multiprocessing.Process(target=writer, args=(d, lock))
r.start()
w.start()
r.join()
w.join()
```

Unfortunately, with this last piece of code, the updated lists do not get shared between the processes. I thought that using proxies would do it but it doesn't.

The only solution I've found is to commit the change made to a list by reassigning the key in the dictionary explicitly. Obviously, if I do so, I don't need to use proxies on lists anymore as it has a unnecessary cost. So a solution I've found so far to replace

```
d[j].append(i)
```

in the writer by:

```
l = d[j]     # Somehow creates a local copy
l.append(i)  # Modify the copy
d[j] = l     # Reassign to commit the change
```

While this does the job, this isn't as trivial to write/understand and might be error prone (forgetting to commit stuff, etc.).

**Am I missing something here? Is there a way to get shared objects within shared objects?**

Just for the sake of completeness, here is the code I have in the end and that does what I what but not in the way I'd like to do it obviously:

```
import multiprocessing, time

manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
d       = manager.dict()
lock    = manager.Lock()
# Add lists:
for i in range(5):
    d[i]    = [] # manager.list() doesn't change anything               

def reader(d, lock):
    for i in range(10):
        with lock:
            print(d)
            sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(1)

def writer(d, lock):
    for i in range(10):
        with lock:
            for j in range(5):
                l = d[j]
                l.append(i)
                d[j] = l
        time.sleep(1)

# Try to read and write the dict:
r = multiprocessing.Process(target=reader, args=(d, lock))
w = multiprocessing.Process(target=writer, args=(d, lock))
r.start()
w.start()
r.join()
w.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed not possible to do this directly, since the proxy object has no way that an internal variable has changed, since it is just pointing to a memory location, and storing the reference to that memory location in stead of the actual values when using custom or more advanced objects.

The documentation has the following to say about this:

Note

Modifications to mutable values or items in dict and list proxies will not be propagated through the manager, because the proxy has no way of knowing when its values or items are modified. To modify such an item, you can re-assign the modified object to the container proxy:

```
# create a list proxy and append a mutable object (a dictionary)
lproxy = manager.list()
lproxy.append({})
# now mutate the dictionary
d = lproxy[0]
d['a'] = 1
d['b'] = 2
# at this point, the changes to d are not yet synced, but by
# reassigning the dictionary, the proxy is notified of the change
lproxy[0] = d
```

Cfr:
http://www.cmi.ac.in/~madhavan/courses/prog2-2015/docs/python-3.4.2-docs-html/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager.list

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.8 has shared lists. They are not full-featured (for one thing, you can't change their length), but they have other characteristics of lists including supporting a mix of types. See the [ShareableList class](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html).